# Warning: session_register() [function.session-register]:

Tags: php, session, memcached, warnings

For the life of me I can not figure out where to even begin to fix this issue. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

> Warning: session_start()
>   [function.session-start]: Cannot find
>   save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 2
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 4
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 5
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 6
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 7
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 8
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 9
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 10
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 13
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 15
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 19
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 22
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 23
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 28
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 31
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 32
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 33
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 34
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 35
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 36
>
> Warning: session_register()
>   [function.session-register]: Cannot
>   find save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/lib/session.inc.php
>   on line 37
>
> Warning: session_start()
>   [function.session-start]: Cannot find
>   save handler 'memcache' - session
>   startup failed in
>   /mnt/r0235/d48/s01/b02d1de7/www/slidesms.com/include/api.php
>   on line 12

Comment: Do you have memcache installed?

Answer (score 0):

if you use memcache to store your sessions. Be sure that memcached is installed. 
apt-get install memcached php5-memcached

Comment: Hey thanx for the input...seems that the php.ini file was causing the problem with memcache. I am using NetFirms for hosting. So soon as I deleted it...all the Warnings went away and I was able to login to the user accounts :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanx for the input...seems that the php.ini file was causing the problem with memcache. I am using NetFirms for hosting. So soon as I deleted it...all the Warnings went away and I was able to login to the user accounts :)